# spring cloud ConsulRibbonClientConfiguration exception

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, consul

When trying to use spring cloud consul I am receiving this error when I try and autowire the Ribbon client during a rest call:

"Error creating bean with name 'consulRibbonClientConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken"

Other times I will get this error instead:
Error creating bean with name 'consulRibbonClientConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.netflix.client.config.CommonClientConfigKey

I had this working before I started trying to use my own configuration classes.  Now depending on what system I run it on I get slightly different errors like the one above where the consul ribbon client configuration is not able to instantiate itself.  Any incite on this problem would be helpful

The configuration class looks like:

```
@Profile("!unit-test")
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@ImportResource("classpath:/hadoopContext.xml")
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class XXXConfiguration..
```

The main is simply:
@SpringBootApplication

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

}
```

The pom is using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.M3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you try with the latest version 1.0.0.RC1?

Comment: I didn't try with the newest release candidate, but given that I had this working earlier with my current release I didn't think this was a likely candidate.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem appears to have been caused by redundant and mismatched dependencies in the maven file. These don't appear to be related to Ribbon, but I guess somehow this cascaded the issue when Ribbon tried to initialize.

For future readers redundant libraries I removed included: spring-tx, hadoop-common, and javax.validation which all needed to be removed to get past this error.